# Difference of using JAR Files and Maven

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, eclipse

Importing the JAR Files in eclipse by  Right click on Project-> Properties-> Java Build Path. JAR files gets imported and it is helping in codes.
                    Nowadays Maven ruled over it. What diff is there between JAR Files and Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a big difference.

When you add JARS in eclipse build path you have to find those jars in the network, download the proper version, place them on your hard drive, set up the config in Eclipse.

Then you might change your mind about the required version, you have find new version in the network, then download, then place jars to your hard drive, then detach old jars in Eclipse project settings, then attach new ones.

After that you might want to move your project to other computer or hand over to another persone. You will then have to comunicate all the lib versions to your mate and they will have to repeat all the steps.

When you use maven, you simply define the lib and the version your project uses in your pom.xml file. This becomes a part of the sources. Now maven takes care of all the stuff with downloading and settings up the class pathes. You can hand over your project to any other guy, which using the IDE with maven support (if we're talking about IDE usage) will open it and will not be care of any extra configuration.